# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'C3714552' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Statement st1 = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs2 = st1.executeQuery("
   SELECT cui_2 
   FROM diagnostico.disease_has_symptom, diagnostico.symptom
   WHERE(
      `symptom`.`cui` = `disease_has_symptom`.`cui_2` AND 
      `symptom`.`cui` = " + sintomas.pop() + ");
");
```

I dont know why i get this error msg...

Comment: I am guessing sintomas holds strings, which you need to delimit with quotes in the query.

Comment: is sintomas.pop()  equal to that value?  You may have to put single quotes around it

Comment: Yes, that was it ! Cheers mate!!!

Answer (score -1):

As @Brad indicates, your main issue involves confusing quotes where `` `symptom`.`cui` = " + sintomas.pop() + "); `` should be: `` `symptom`.`cui` = ' + sintomas.pop() + '); ``.

Why is this the case? According to the [SQL-ANSI 92](https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/ansi-sql-standards/) (an older version of the formal, industry standard of the SQL language that most RDBMS's adhere to including SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL, etc.), single quotes and double quotes are used for different purposes.

**Double quotes** are used for identifiers including column and table names such as `"symptom"."cui"`.

Under,  section 5.2  and  of [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) doc, below is the function definition of the delimited identifier:

```
<delimited identifier> ::=
   <double quote> <delimited identifier body> <double quote>
```

Below are few common uses of this type:

- Double quotes allow spaces, according to 5.2 - Syntax Rules

  ```
  2) With the exception of the <space> character explicitly contained
      in <timestamp string> and <interval string> and the permitted
      <separator>s in <bit string literal>s and <hex string literal>s,
      a <token>, other than a <character string literal>, a <national
      character string literal>, or a <delimited identifier>, shall not 
      include a <space> character or other <separator>.
  ```
- Double quotes impose case sensitivity, compared to regular identifiers:

  ```
  13)A <regular identifier> and a <delimited identifier> are equivalent 
      if the <identifier body> of the <regular identifier> (with
      every letter that is a lower-case letter replaced by the equiva-
      lent upper-case letter or letters) and the <delimited identifier
      body> of the <delimited identifier> (with all occurrences of
      <quote> replaced by <quote symbol> and all occurrences of <dou-
      blequote symbol> replaced by <double quote>), considered as
      the repetition of a <character string literal> that specifies a
      <character set specification> of SQL_TEXT and an implementation-
      defined collation that is sensitive to case, compare equally
      according to the comparison rules in Subclause 8.2, "<comparison
      predicate>".
  ```

However, some RDBMS's have their own escaping symbols for special characters, spaces, and [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) which are not ANSI standards. For example, SQL Server can use square brackets `[...]`; and MySQL can use backticks `` `...` ``.

---

**Single quotes** are used to enclose string literals within char, varchar, text data type columns such as `'C3714552'`. Your error message is raised because you use double quotes and the MySQL engine is then looking for a column identifier since you wrap the value in double quotes.

Under 5.3  of [SQL-92](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) doc, below is the definition of a string literal (no double quote present):

```
 <character string literal> ::=
      [ <introducer><character set specification> ]
      <quote> [ <character representation>... ] <quote>
        [ { <separator>... <quote> [ <character representation>... ] <quote> }... ]
```

And under 5.3 - Syntax Rules:

```
 1) In a <character string literal> or <national character string
    literal>, the sequence:

      <quote> <character representation>... <quote>
      <separator>... <quote> <character representation>... <quote>

    is equivalent to the sequence

      <quote> <character representation>... <character representa-
      tion>... <quote>
```

---

With that said, MySQL provides various non-ANSI [modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-important) which may use double quotes for string literals. But possibly backend APIs like JDBC or ODBC, drivers default to ANSI standards.